# Aligning two list of different size for a tile matching game in python, game board formatting

Tags: python

I am making a tile matching game and am struggling when formatting the game board.
I want it to look like below:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6    
A --- --- --- --- --- ---
B --- --- --- --- --- ---
C --- --- --- --- --- ---
D --- --- --- --- --- ---
E --- --- --- --- --- ---
F --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

I have two lists. One with random words divided into lists of six words within the list. And one with the letters A-F and "---" for each of the words.

```
game_board = [['act', 'age', 'era', 'fun', 'hen', 'fog'], 
['far', 'dog', 'dog', 'gum', 'jam', 'jar'], 
['jar', 'key', 'hen', 'map', 'age', 'pie'], 
['fog', 'two', 'jam', 'era', 'not', 'hem'], 
['far', 'two', 'gum', 'hem', 'act', 'not'], 
['key', 'ski', 'map', 'ski', 'pie', 'fun']]

visible_board = [['A', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['B', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['C', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['D', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['E', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['F', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---']]
```

My current board looks how I want it to. However, when I try to align these the first word becomes "hidden" behind the first letter instead of the first "---". And what I want is for the first word in game_board to be aligned with the first "---" in visible_board etc.

This is the code that I am using now (coordinates are entered as "A1" etc.):

```
game_board = [['act', 'age', 'era', 'fun', 'hen', 'fog'], 
['far', 'dog', 'dog', 'gum', 'jam', 'jar'], 
['jar', 'key', 'hen', 'map', 'age', 'pie'], 
['fog', 'two', 'jam', 'era', 'not', 'hem'], 
['far', 'two', 'gum', 'hem', 'act', 'not'], 
['key', 'ski', 'map', 'ski', 'pie', 'fun']]

visible_board = [['A', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['B', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['C', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['D', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['E', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'], 
['F', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---']]

letters_to_numbers = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5}

def choice():
    coor_1 = list(input('Coordinates1: ').upper())
    r_1, c_1 = (letters_to_numbers[coor_1[0]], int(coor_1[1]))
    board((r_1, c_1))
    coor_2 = list(input('Coordinates2: ').upper())
    r_2, c_2 = (letters_to_numbers[coor_2[0]], int(coor_2[1]))
    board((r_1, c_1), (r_2, c_2))

    if game_board[r_1][c_1] == game_board[r_2][c_2]:
        print('You found a pair.')
        visible_board[r_1][c_1] = game_board[r_1][c_1]
        visible_board[r_2][c_2] = game_board[r_2][c_2]
    else:
        print('Try again.')
        return True

def board(*card):
    print("   1   2   3   4   5   6")
    for row in range(6):
        for column in range(7):
            if (row,column) in card:
                print(game_board[row][column], end=' ')
            else:
                print(visible_board[row][column], end=' ')
        print()
board()

while choice():
    pass
```

The problem is that "game_board" has 6 elements in each row and "visible_board" has seven. Because of this the coordinate A0 exists but not A6. Is there something I can do to add the letters A-F to each row without them being in the list "visible_board" so that they will not overlap with the elements in "game_board". Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you provide more of your code? As far I can see now, the visible board has 7 elements in each row, whereas the game board has 6. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Do you know how I can add the letters without them having to be in the list visible board?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. A simple runnable code (not an uncalled function with an undefined variable `card`) and the current board you have and the one you expect to have

Comment: By the way possible bug: putting the same coordinate twice gives a match

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the actual problem you have, but how about just accessing `c-1`? i.e. `visible_board[r_1][c_1] = game_board[r_1][c_1-1]`. Or alternatively, just insert a dummy value to `game_board` in each row: `['', 'act', 'age', 'era', 'fun', 'hen', 'fog']`

Comment: Thank you! will try to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could probably just adjust indexing at all locations to compensate for the fact that your visible board has 7 columns while the game board has only 6, the easier option is probably to just not include the row labels in the visible board. An example of how that could be done:

```
game_board = [['act', 'age', 'era', 'fun', 'hen', 'fog'], 
['far', 'dog', 'dog', 'gum', 'jam', 'jar'], 
['jar', 'key', 'hen', 'map', 'age', 'pie'], 
['fog', 'two', 'jam', 'era', 'not', 'hem'], 
['far', 'two', 'gum', 'hem', 'act', 'not'], 
['key', 'ski', 'map', 'ski', 'pie', 'fun']]

visible_board = [['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'],
['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'],
['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'],
['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'],
['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---'],
['---', '---', '---', '---', '---', '---']]

letters_to_numbers = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5}

row_labels = list(letters_to_numbers.keys())

def choice():
    coor_1 = list(input('Coordinates1: ').upper())
    r_1, c_1 = (letters_to_numbers[coor_1[0]], int(coor_1[1]))
    board((r_1, c_1))
    coor_2 = list(input('Coordinates2: ').upper())
    r_2, c_2 = (letters_to_numbers[coor_2[0]], int(coor_2[1]))
    board((r_1, c_1), (r_2, c_2))

    if game_board[r_1][c_1] == game_board[r_2][c_2]:
        print('You found a pair.')
        visible_board[r_1][c_1] = game_board[r_1][c_1]
        visible_board[r_2][c_2] = game_board[r_2][c_2]
    else:
        print('Try again.')
        return True

def board(*card):
    print("   1   2   3   4   5   6")
    for row in range(6):
        print(row_labels[row], end=' ')
        for column in range(0, 6):
            if (row,column) in card:
                print(game_board[row][column], end=' ')
            else:
                print(visible_board[row][column], end=' ')
        print()
board()

while choice():
    pass
```